# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt generating tkinter failure when used with bazel

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, bazel

I am trying to use matplotlib in a python script with Bazel.

When doing

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get the error

> File
> "/home/usr/.cache/bazel/_bazel_usr/5d92cd43b40817a708cea90464c6d466/execroot/project/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/.../test.runfiles/project/.../test.py",
> line 1, in 
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   File "/home/usr/.cache/bazel/_bazel_usr/5d92cd43b40817a708cea90464c6d466/execroot/project/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/.../test.runfiles/matplotlib_py38_linux/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
> line 2356, in 
> switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])   File "/home/usr/.cache/bazel/_bazel_usr/5d92cd43b40817a708cea90464c6d466/execroot/project/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/.../test.runfiles/matplotlib_py38_linux/matplotlib/**init**.py",
> line 833, in **getitem**
> plt.switch_backend(rcsetup._auto_backend_sentinel)   File "/home/usr/.cache/bazel/_bazel_usr/5d92cd43b40817a708cea90464c6d466/execroot/project/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/.../test.runfiles/matplotlib_py38_linux/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
> line 204, in switch_backend
> switch_backend(candidate)   File "/home/usr/.cache/bazel/_bazel_usr/5d92cd43b40817a708cea90464c6d466/execroot/project/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/.../test.runfiles/matplotlib_py38_linux/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
> line 221, in switch_backend
> backend_mod = importlib.import_module(backend_name)   File "/home/usr/.cache/bazel/_bazel_usr/5d92cd43b40817a708cea90464c6d466/external/hermetic_python_3_8_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/python3.8/importlib/**init**.py",
> line 127, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "/home/usr/.cache/bazel/_bazel_usr/5d92cd43b40817a708cea90464c6d466/execroot/project/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/.../test.runfiles/matplotlib_py38_linux/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py",
> line 1, in 
> from . import _backend_tk   File "/home/usr/.cache/bazel/_bazel_usr/5d92cd43b40817a708cea90464c6d466/execroot/project/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/.../test.runfiles/matplotlib_py38_linux/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py",
> line 22, in 
> from . import _tkagg AttributeError: module '_tkinter' has no attribute '**file**'

Python version: 3.8.15
Matplotlib version: 3.5.3 (or 3.1.3 depending on the configuration).
UI.

My bazel target can be as simple as:

```
py_binary(
    name = "test",
    srcs = [
        "test.py",
    ],
    deps = ["@matplotlib_py38//:lib",],
)
```

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7428/ check duplicate

Comment: How is that a duplicate? I did not build from source

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, all I could find are these closed ticket, but I can't understand why: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/25944